# replace string content using .* in java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I am trying to capture the '' part and it is possible that the content inside the '<' and '>' symbols may vary. It might also contain some dots. So I'm trying

```
String Inputstr = "SOME <Module Name> Module";                  
ptrn = Pattern.compile("<.*>", Pattern.DOTALL);
mtch = ptrn.matcher(Inputstr);
if (mtch.matches()) {
    // Do a replacement operation
}
```

But the problem is that it doesn't go inside the if conditional at all.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can debug your regex at https://www.debuggex.com .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `find` and not `matches`. (`matches` requires the entire string to match.)

```
String Inputstr = "SOME <Module Name> Module";                  
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("<.*>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher mtch = ptrn.matcher(Inputstr);
if (mtch.find()) {
    System.out.println("The <...> part: " + mtch.group());  // <Module Name>
}
```

Also, you don't need `DOTALL` unless you have new-line characters between `<` and `>`.

If you actually want to replace the module name with another string, you could do:

```
String Inputstr = "SOME <Module Name> Module";                  
String outputStr = Inputstr.replaceAll("<.*>", "A-module-name");
                            ^^^^^^^^^^
System.out.println(outputStr);  // "SOME A-module-name Module"
```

Comment: Personally I use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for these kind of String operations, but above is also good.

Comment: Thank you! seems I've not read the documentation carefully. My bad...

find(): Returns true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

match(): Returns true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
Inputstr.replaceAll("<.*>", replaceText);
```

that would be a much shorter solution.

By the way:By convention the first letter of variablenames are written in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

It's tidier and more readable to use

```
Inputstr.replaceAll("<.*>", "replaced text here");
```